# My WordPress plugin takes too long to execute

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress plugin that opens an Excel file and updates the database based on the information in the spreadsheet. My code works great... for about 15,000 rows. After that the script just ends. The rows to that point are read and the database updated accordingly. I'm assuming I'm hitting a time out limit, memory limit or some other hard limit before I get to my last row (roughly 60,000). No error is recorded in the PHP error log.

I've tried `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` but that didn't change anything. I don't have control of the server, everything I do has to be done in PHP. What is the proper way ensure that my script can make it through such a ridiculous spreadsheet?

Comment: Think about to use JavaScript / jQuery  AJAX requests to read your in iterations.

Comment: The default execution time in PHP is 30 seconds afaik. You can perhaps use http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php set_time_limit(90); to check if it works for more than 15k rows. This could give you an idea of tinkering around with the time limit.

Comment: Could be batching via [wp-cron](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron) be an option?

Answer (score 1):

It is alway best to not operate at the edge of php limits.

You could make a number of smaller batch ajax calls. For example, you could make your ajax script perform 5,000 rows at a time, and then return the number of rows remaining. Then your client code on the browser knows there's still some left to process and calls the background php via ajax again, perhaps with a counter indicating the current position.